# Separate undo buffer for each textarea in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit

In the simple example below, the current behavior is that the undo buffer is "global", in the sense that if you type something in `textarea1`, then type something in `textarea2` and then go back to `textarea1` and type something, and then press **Ctrl+Z** a few times to undo, it will jump between the text areas, since there only seems to be one undo buffer.

Is it possible to have a separate undo buffer for each textarea, as if they were separate "files"?

If this is browser specific (which I suspect), is there a possibility to achieve this in Chrome?, or any other browser platform for that sake?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
        <textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the same for input fields as well

Comment: Other than intercepting ctrl + z, and then putting in place your own logic, you could go the easier (and more reliable) route of writing your own undo logic (custom) to respond to a *different* keyboard shortcut and train your users on it.